# Ibeacon didRangeBeacons delayed call in the background

Tags: ios, swift, background, beacon

When the iphone(iOS 8+) goes into deep sleep or is killed, the function call delay (locationManager: didRangeBeacons: inRegion :) or (locationManager: didDetermineState: forRegion :) is delayed for 3s ~ 3min, sometimes it needs to light up the screen to be triggered. In the program Using CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey recovery mechanism, I have added background model in info.plist.How to improve the trigger rate, hardware broadcast frequency and other parameters have any requirements? Please tell me thank you.

Comment: The reported behavior does not match what I have seen.   If you are out of region and the app is in the background, a beacon appearing will typically give a callback to your app in 1-2 seconds.   The same holds true if you are out of region then kill your app and then a beacon appears.   I cannot say the same about deep sleep without knowing more about what you mean there.   But in general I find that the timing is no different with your app recently put to the background than in the other cases you describe.

Comment: Because I need to scan Bluetooth in the background, for example when I kill the app and get in range, sometimes it fires very quickly, sometimes it takes a long time to fire (didRangeBeacons or didDetermineState) or does not respond, but when I click Bright screen will trigger immediately DidDetermineState, and then perform Ble scan, most of the time it is necessary to light up the screen before they can

Comment: Ok, but if you simply put the app to the background and wait a bit before bringing into beacon proximity, are you saying it ALWAYS fires didEnter within a second or two?

Comment: yeah，if put the app to the backgroud and wait a bit before bringing in to beacon proximit  will fires didEnte immediately，when I kill the app waiting for about 30min, you need to wait a long time or need to light the screen fires didEnte

Comment: Can you show your code that sets up monitoring?